# Google's organization G suite and user history

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-account

Does the admin of an organization's G suite have access to the browsing history of users that logged in to chrome with the organization account?

For example, I have a myname@company.com account that's in G suit, does the company have access to my browsing history?

Also, if the admin has access to all the mails, they probably also have access to my account, so what's stopping them from logging into my account and syncing all of my history?

Answer (score 1):

No. I am a G Suite admin, and I have no access to users' browser history.

Comment: @McDonald's I'm not sure why you think it's off topic. Superuser says it's for "...specific issues with computer software". G Suite is computer software, and this is a specific issue.

Comment: @McDonald's The distinction between cloud service and local software doesn't make sense any more, and this group should stop trying to make such a distinction. Most software has both cloud and local elements. But the specific question concerns Chrome, which is definitely tilted towards the local side -- the account login that the question concerns is one of the few cloud elements.

Comment: My bad, my bad.... I was totally wrong obviously so I did send you the question though when I saw and wondered so thank you for clarifying. I was thinking they were asking is a cloud service provider for the entire G Sutie product had access... Not like a local site, or cloud site admin. Meaning the server admins that maintain the hosted service of the hosted service they provide is what I was thinking.

Comment: In any event your answer is rather vague to criticize you a little here, because the system flagged this in Review and that's the only reason I looked at this. I wanted to be sure you understand that. Yes, I understand, I was wrong, this is on-topic; your question still lacks the detail to support what you say is the case even though it may answer the question and thus this is the only reason I invaded your space man.

Comment: But what's stopping the admin from logging into my account and seeing all of my synced history?